# In clean architecture between entity layer and use-case layer. What is the use-case boundary?

Tags: javascript, rest, oop, design-patterns, clean-architecture

As I understand Entity caries fundamental properties, methods and validations. An **User Entity** would have name, DoB...email, verified, and what ever deemed 'core' to this project. For instance, one requires **phone number** while a complete different project would deem **phone number** as not necessary but mailing address is.

So then, moving out side of Entity layer, we have the Use-Case layer which depends on entity layer. I imagine this use-case as something slightly more flexible than entity. So this layer allows us to write additional logic and calculations while making use of  existing entity or multiple entities.

But my first uncertainty lies whether use-case can create derived values(DoB => Age) from entity properties and even persist them in storage or does it need to already exist in User Entity class already ? Secondly, does use-case layer even NEED to use entity, could I have a use-case that literally just sums(a, b) and may or may not persist that in storage anyways? Thirdly, when persisting entity related properties into database, does retrieving them require once again validation, is this redundant and hurting performance?

Finally, the bigger quesetion is, what is use-case ? should use-case mean to be adaptable by being agnostic of where the inputs comes from and what it serves to? does this just mean the inversion dependency removes the responsibility of what framework it ties to. I.e. using express or Koa or plain http wouldn't force a rewrite of core logic . OR does it mean adaptable to something even greater? like whether it serves directly at the terminal-related applications or api request/response-like-applications via web server?

If its the latter, then it's confusing to me, because it has to be agnostic where it gets/goes, yet these outputs resembles the very medium they will deliver to. for instance, designing a restFUL api, a use case may be...

getUserPosts(userId, limit, offset). which will output a format best for web api consumers (that to me is the application logic right? for a specific application). And it's unlikely that I'll reuse the use-case getUserPost for a different requestor (some terminal interface that runs locally, which wants more detailed response), more or less. So to me i see it shines when the times comes to switch between application-specific framework like between express/koa/httprequest/connect for a restapi for the same application or node.js/bun environment to interact with the same terminal. Rather than all mightly one usecase that criss-cross any kind of application(webservice and terminal simultaneously or any other).

If it is allmighty, should use-case be designed with more generalized purpose? Make them take more configurable? like previously i could've add more parameters getUserPosts(userId, limit, offset, sideloadingConfig, expandedConfig, format: 'obj' | 'csv' | 'json' ), I suppose the forethought to anticipate different usage and scaling requires experience - unless this is where the open-close principle shines to make it ready to be expandable? Or is it just easier to make a separate use-case like getUserPostsWebServices and getUserPostsForLocal , getPremiumUsersPostsForWebServices - this makes sense to me, because now each use-case has its own constraints, it is not possible for WebServieces to reach anymore data fetch/manipulation than PostsForLocal or getPremiumUsersPostsForWebServices offers. and our reusability of WebServices does not tie to any webserver framework. I suppose this is where I would draw the line for use-case, but I'm inexperienced, and I don't know the answer to this.

I know this has been a regurgitation of my understanding rather than a concrete question, but it still points to the quesiton of what the boundary and defintion of use-case is in clean architecture. Thanks for reading, would anyone chime to clarify anything I said wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> But my first uncertainty lies whether use-case can create derived values(DoB => Age) from entity properties and even persist them in storage or does it need to already exist in User Entity class already ?

The age of a user is directly derived from the date of birth. I think the way it is calculated is the same between different applications. Thus it is an application agnostic logic and should be placed in the entity.

Defining a `User.getAge` method does not mean that it must be persisted. The entities in the clean architecture are business object that encapsulate application agnostic business rules.

The properties that are persisted is decided in the repository. Usually you only persist the basic properties, not derived. But if you need to query entities by derived properties they can be persisted too.

Persisting time dependent properties is a bit tricky, since they change as time goes by. E.g. if you persist a user's age and it is 17 at the time you persist it, it might be 18 a few days or eveh hours later. If you have a use case that searches for all users that are 18 to send them an email, you will not find all. Time dependent properties need a kind of heart beat use case that is triggered by a scheduler and just loads (streams) all entities and just persists them again. The repository will then persist the actual value of age and it can be found by other queries.

> Secondly, does use-case layer even NEED to use entity, could I have a use-case that literally just sums(a, b) and may or may not persist that in storage anyways?

The use case layer usually uses entities. If you use case would be as simple as sum two numbers it must not use entities, but I guess this is a rare case.

Even very small use cases like `sums(a, b)` can require the use of entities, if there are rules on `a` and `b`. This can be very simple rules like `a` and `b` must be positive integer values. But even if there are no rules it can make sense to create entities, because if `a` and `be` are custom entities you can give them a name to emphasize that they belong to a critial business concept.

> Thirdly, when persisting entity related properties into database, does retrieving them require once again validation, is this redundant and hurting performance?

Usually your application is the only client of the database. If so then your application ensures that only valid entities are stored to the database.  Thus it is usually not required to validate them again.

Valid can be context dependent, e.g. if you have an entity named `PostDraft` it should be clear that a draft doesn't have the same validation rules then a `PublishedPost`.

Finally a note to the performance concerns. The first rule is measure don't guess. Write a simple test that creates, e.g. 1.000.000 entities, and validates them. Usually a database query and/or the network traffic, or I/O in common, are performance issues and not in memory computation. Of cource you can write code that uses weird loops that mess up performance, but often this is not the case.

> Finally, the bigger quesetion is, what is use-case ? should use-case mean to be adaptable by being agnostic of where the inputs comes from and what it serves to? does this just mean the inversion dependency removes the responsibility of what framework it ties to. I.e. using express or Koa or plain http wouldn't force a rewrite of core logic . OR does it mean adaptable to something even greater? like whether it serves directly at the terminal-related applications or api request/response-like-applications via web server?

A use case is is an application dependent business logic. There are different reasons why the clean architecture (and also others like the hexagonal) make them independent of the I/O mechanism. One is that it is independent of frameworks. This makes them easy to test. If a use case would depend on an http controller or better said you implemented the use case in an http controller, e.g. a rest controller, it means that you need to start up an http server, open a socket, write the http request, read the http response, extract the data you need to test it. Even there are frameworks and tools that make such an test easy, these tools must finally start a server and this takes time. Tests that are slow are not executed often, are they? And tests are the basis for refactoring. If you don't have tests or the tests ran slow you do not execute them. If you do not execute them you do not refactor. So the code must rot.

In my opinion the testability is most import and decoupling use cases from any details, like uncle bob names the outer layers, increases the testability of use cases. Use cases are the heart of an application. That's why they should be easy testable and be protected from any dependency to details so that they do not need to be touched in case of a detail change.

> If it is allmighty, should use-case be designed with more generalized purpose? Make them take more configurable? like previously i could've add more parameters getUserPosts(userId, limit, offset, sideloadingConfig, expandedConfig, format: 'obj' | 'csv' | 'json' )

I don't think so. Especially the *sideloadingConfig*, *format* like *json* or *csv* are not parameters for a use case. These parameters belong to a specific kind of frontend or better said to a specific kind of controllers. A use-case provides the raw business data. It is the responsibility of a controller or better a presenter to format them.